# How to implement a drawer on Flutter that closes itself when tapped on the option that's already displayed?

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a drawer that closes itself if the user taps on the option which the app is currently showing. My implementation was:

```
int currentPageIndex = 0;
void pageLoader(BuildContext context, int pageIndex){
    switch(pageIndex){
      case 0:
        if(currentPageIndex != 0){
          currentPageIndex = 0;
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page0())
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        if(currentPageIndex != 1){
          currentPageIndex = 1;
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Page1())
          );
        } else {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
        break;
      ...
    }
  }
```

And the onTap properties of my listtiles are in this format:

```
onTap: () => pageLoader(context, index) //index being a number
```

This approach bugs out when the user taps the back button, since the displayed page changes without changing the currentPageIndex variable. How can I write a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a ScaffoldState key

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,)
```

At the place where you are handling the Tap thing after that line writes the below code also.

For the left drawer

```
toggleDrawer() async {
  if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
  } else {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
  }
}
```

For the right drawer

```
toggleDrawer() async {
  if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
  } else {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
  }
}
```